# How to select options in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have generated SELECT list by php.
How I can select some option in this select list?

```
<select name="language[]" ng-model="formData.language" id="language" ng-required="true">
<option value="72" selected="selected">Fulfulde</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not clear at all what you are asking. Is `ng-model` not working?

Comment: I mean, that in this HTML code there is `selected="selected"` element, but Angular does not selected this element. How do it? Or how to select option when I have array of values that must be selected?

Comment: You are looking at element *attributes*, which are **not** the same as element *properties*. Please provide a demo in http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net that replicates your problem. If you pass the correct values to `formData.language` used as your `ng-model` there should be no problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ng-options attribute

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name group by color.shade disable when color.notAnOption for color in colors"> </select>
```

For more info my go through this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use `ng-options` directive to work with select box.

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/O4eIiXAarXtc0NYoDvSO?p=preview)